# Intel wifi card not working on Ubuntu iwlwifi error on boot and no wi-fi adapter found

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

So I tried about everything to get my wi-fi card to work.

I have a ASUS ZenBook 14 UX433FN with Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS.

This laptop doesn't have a switch or key combination to toggle wi-fi.

I have a windows dual boot but fast boot is disabled.

Also secure boot is disabled.

```
$ uname -r
5.4.0-126-generic
```

```
$ iwconfig
br-d590c9204e94  no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

enx00e04c6800bf  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf 
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

`$ dmesg | grep iwl`

https://pastebin.com/x2W3KCYK

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:b431c000-b431ffff
```

`$ ls /lib/firmware/ | grep iwl`

https://pastebin.com/9rqQQM5W

Comment: "This laptop doesn't have a switch to toggle wi-fi." I believe it has a key combination, something like Fn+F2. Please recheck. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Hi thanks for the welcome. fn+F2 turns the volume down and all the F keys do have fn actions but none linked to wi-fi.